# Is LEM Actually Invoked in the Classic Irrational Exponent Argument

Tags: logic

I am almost positive this has been discussed on here but I can't seem to find it after an hour of searching. Please redirect if so.

There is a classic non-constructive argument we have probably all seen to the assertion that "There exists irrational $x,y$ such that $x^y$ is rational. The argument asserts that the number $\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$ must be rational or irrational (exclusive or), and either case yields the result, thus the assertion is true by exhaustion of the cases.

My question is: does the statement "for any real number $x$, $x$ is either rational or irrational" actually assume the Law of the Excluded Middle? The reason I think it does not is because the literal definition of irrational is that it is $not$ rational, so if the statement '$x$ is rational' is either true or false by the principle of bivalence, but being false means 'there does not exist $a,b$ such that $x = \frac{a}{b}$' which is the definition  of irrational. In this situation, it seems it can be justified without LEM that irrational numbers form a disjoint union of real numbers. Or am I making a jump in interpretting 'what it means' for a statement to be false? Perhaps what allows me to even quantify or interpret what it means for the statement to be false is where I am using LEM? If someone did not accept LEM could they raise a logical flaw with the argument given above?

This is kind of abstract and more rooted in logic/philosophy and I think (at least in most US universities) the approach to teaching collegiate mathematics tends to yield confusion about logic. Logic seems to be a bigger bubble that encompasses mathematics so I may not understand the more abstract setting in which these concepts make sense.

Comment: What do you think "bivalence" means if not "the middle is excluded"?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins I think bivalence means that any $P$ is either true or false, and LEM means $(P \or \neg P)$

Comment: Can you convince yourself that bivalence implies LEM?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Would a constructive mathematician not argue that bivalence holds but LEM should not?

Comment: Turns out I'm wrong, there are bivalent logics in which LEM does not hold and intuitionistic logic is one such example. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Let me address your question more specifically. You say "for any real number $x$, $x$ is either rational or irrational." If we agree that irrational means nothing but $\neg R(x)$, a word for word translation of that statement is $\forall x (R(x) \lor \neg R(x))$, where $R(x)$ is the statement "$x$ is rational."

Comment: At some point in your argument you say that "$R(x)$ is false" is the same as $\neg R(x)$. Bivalence is not enough for that conclusion because bivalence does not guarantee you that the negation of any true statement is false. It only guarantees that there are two logical values. If you want the negation of a true statement to automatically be false, you need something like LEM, noncontradiction, or double negation elimination.

Comment: After further reading it seems like even that is contested in some logical systems. That is, there are systems which are bivalent and in which, by definition, $\neg P$ is the same as $P \implies \bot$. So my final answer is that the answer to your question depends strongly on which logic you endorse.

Comment: See also the disjunction property in intuitionistic logic

Comment: If not made explicit otherwise, I'd default to syntactic arguments only. Instead of "disregarding syntactic LEM but believing in semantic bivalence" for propositions, maybe a more helpful first approximation is the trichotomy "provable", "rejectable" (i.e. negation provable) or "I don't know and am not sure if I one can ever find out". / Taking a standard axiomatization with LEM and dropping LEM will put you in a position where you can't use decidability of rationality of reals. Now you don't need to add back full LEM, I think it's equivalent to the analytical limited principle of omniscience.

Answer (score -1):

As it stands, the statement “for any real number $x$, $x$ is either rational or irrational” does not assume law of excluded middle.

The statement “for any real number $x$, $x$ is either rational or not-rational” would assume law of excluded middle, in which case ‘not-rational’ might or might not coincide with ‘irrational’ and if it coincided, we would call ‘irrational’ instead of ‘not-rational’. But it is conceivable that it might well coincide with the union of two sets numbers, suppose irrational numbers and what we would call "anti-rational" numbers.

To express symbolically, the former statement tells that

$$\forall x(x\in\mathbb{R}\rightarrow(x\in\mathbb{Q}\vee x\in\mathbb{P}))$$

This does not exemplify the law of excluded by itself, for the predicates $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{P}$ are distinct in the formal language of logic. However, the later statement

$$\forall x(x\in\mathbb{R}\rightarrow(x\in\mathbb{Q}\vee \neg(x\in\mathbb{Q})))$$

or equivalently,

$$\forall x(x\in\mathbb{R}\rightarrow(x\in\mathbb{Q}\vee x\not\in\mathbb{Q}))$$

exemplifies the law of excluded middle, for the predicates at stake are one and the same in the formal language of logic.

Compare these to the imaginary example

$$\forall x(x\in\mathbb{R}\rightarrow(x\in\mathbb{Q}\vee x\in\mathbb{P}\vee x\in\mathbb{Q}^{anti}))$$

It is a fact of mathematics, not logical necessitation, that there is no such set as $\mathbb{Q}^{anti}$.

Anyway, the idea that the proof is non-constructive does not hinge on this. For further discussion, I cite the proof referred from Michael Dummett's *[Elements of Intuitionism](https://archive.org/details/elementsofintuit0000dumm)* (1st edition, p. 10 and 2nd edition, p. 6, see the ensuing discussion)

> Theorem 1.1 There are solutions of $x^{y} = z$ with $x$ and $y$
> irrational and $z$  rational.
>
> Proof. $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, and $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$ is either
> rational or irrational. If it is rational, put $x = \sqrt{2}, y =
> > \sqrt{2}$ so that $z = \sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$, which, by hypothesis, is
> rational. If, on the other hand,  $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$ is irrational,
> put $x = \sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$ and $y =\sqrt{2}$, so that $z = (\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}})^\sqrt{2} = \sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}} = 2$, which is
> certainly rational. Thus in either case a solution exists.

Notice that the proof does not discern which one from the pair of numbers $(x, y$ falls under the predicate of being a rational number (equivalently, an irrational number). That makes the proof non-nconstructive.

To recapitulate, the world may offer us two options or more than two options. If two options A and B are presented, then B naturally coincide with not-A. But the law of excluded middle dictates merely two *logical* options, however the world turns out to be.

It is a *mathematical fact* (i.e., of the world) that there are two complementary sets of numbers, rational and irrational. It is not a *logical truth*. But since mathematics offers two choices, it coincides with the law of excluded middle. Compare this to the proof: The offered options are logical, not mathematical, for we do not know which is which.